# Statuses on Order partial not reflecting in button output with elsif use

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having issues where an Order's button won't change it's value based on it's `status` integer when put through an `elsif` statement. This is my `elsif`

```
    <%if o.status = 1%>
        <button class="btn btn-success"><%= link_to "Accept", accept_path(id: o.id) %> </button><!-- method: :post Accept-->
    <%elsif o.status = 2 %>
        <button class="btn btn-success">"COMPLETED" </button><!--Working-->
    <%elsif o.status = 3%>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Completed </button><!--Review-->
    <%elsif o.status = 4%>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button><!--Confirmed-->
    <%elsif o.status = 5%>
        <button class="btn btn-success">PAID</button><!--Paid-->
    <%else%>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Contact for Issues</button> <!--Contact-->
    <%end%>
```

Currently the button is showing the "Accept"/Status: 1 value no matter what the order's status integer value is.

When giving my Index what `obj` to use I use

```
@orders = Order.where(user_id: nil)
@orders_user = current_user.orders
```

And these are rendered in a partial like so `<%= render 'order', obj: @orders_user%>`

I have no clue why this isn't working but when I make the first if statement to `nil` instead of 1 the button immediately says "COMPLETED" which is for `status = 2`

How i assign the status, there is an error that comes up with the `.save?` part of it as well but I was going to fix that later, but it could also be the issue here.

```
   def create
       @order = Order.where(order_params).first_or_create
       @order.status = 1
    if @order.save?
        flash[:success] = "Order was successfully made"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        #flash error
        render 'new'
   end
  end
```

The log from trying to create the order in the view is `undefined method`save?' for # Did you mean? save save!` but in the console the log is

```
   Started POST "/order" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-30 23:00:53 +1200
    Processing by OrderController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"w3pQ3ZeluOpm0Wh9wq1h1nPZtd5zOysTJgFDrRpBpDBaSs5LYheLvO/HU6O94WFsbaugYvMYuGZNVO3bXfOPMQ==", "order"=>{"name"=>"stackoverflow", "email"=>"so@so.com", "company"=>"sososo", "event_type"=>"Birthday", "country"=>"United Kingdom", "description"=>"sososo"}, "commit"=>"Create Order"}
      Order Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."name" = $1 AND "orders"."company" = $2 AND "orders"."email" = $3 AND "orders"."event_type" = $4 AND "orders"."country" = $5 AND "orders"."description" = $6 ORDER BY "orders"."id" ASC LIMIT $7  [["name", "stackoverflow"], ["company", "sososo"], ["email", "so@so.com"], ["event_type", "Birthday"], ["country", "United Kingdom"], ["description", "sososo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN
      Order Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE LOWER("orders"."email") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["email", "so@so.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("name", "company", "email", "event_type", "country", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "stackoverflow"], ["company", "sososo"], ["email", "so@so.com"], ["event_type", "Birthday"], ["country", "United Kingdom"], ["description", "sososo"], ["created_at", 2017-06-30 11:00:53 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-30 11:00:53 UTC]]
       (0.9ms)  COMMIT
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN
      Order Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE LOWER("orders"."email") = LOWER($1) AND ("orders"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["email", "so@so.com"], ["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "orders" SET "status" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "orders"."id" = $3  [["status", 1], ["updated_at", 2017-06-30 11:00:53 UTC], ["id", 4]]
       (0.3ms)  COMMIT
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)



    NoMethodError (undefined method `save?' for #<Order:0x007fd6416ea130>
        Did you mean?  save
                   save!):

    app/controllers/order_controller.rb:27:in `create'
      Rendering /Users/Jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
      Rendering /Users/Jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
      Rendered /Users/Jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (2.3ms)
      Rendering /Users/Jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
      Rendered /Users/Jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)
      Rendering /Users/Jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
      Rendered /Users/Jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
      Rendered /Users/Jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (64.3ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `=` to `==`
You are assigning 1 to o.status instead of comparing.

```
  <%if o.status == 1%>
    <button class="btn btn-success"><%= link_to "Accept", accept_path(id: o.id) %> </button><!-- method: :post Accept-->
<%elsif o.status == 2 %>
    <button class="btn btn-success">"COMPLETED" </button><!--Working-->
<%elsif o.status == 3%>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Completed </button><!--Review-->
<%elsif o.status == 4%>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button><!--Confirmed-->
<%elsif o.status == 5%>
    <button class="btn btn-success">PAID</button><!--Paid-->
<%else%>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Contact for Issues</button> <!--Contact-->
<%end%>
```

Comment: when I use the `==` to compare it immediately skips to the "Contact for Issues" part despite me assigning a status in the creation of an `Order` and verifying that the status has been set in the rails console

Comment: how are you assigning the status?  Can you give more details?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Are you able to save the @order using save?
I get an error undefined method `save?`
Try `save` instead of `save?`

Comment: The order doesn't save the status actually

Comment: Could you show the logs from where you can see the @order persisting?

Comment: There is not `save?` method for persisting ActiveRecord objects. 
Replace `save?` by `save` in `if @order.save?` and replace `=` by `==` in the view. And it should work.